# If $a$ is a unit and $b$ is a zero divisor in a ring $R$, then $ab$ is a zero divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that $ax=1$ has a nonzero solution, $bx = 0$ has a nonzero solution. I am of course trying to show that $(ab)(x) = 0$ has a nonzero solution.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Don't use the symbol $x$ everywhere; use different names for the different solutions, it will help clarify things. For example: we are supposing that $bc=0$ where $b\neq 0$ and $c\neq 0$. Now you're looking for something non-zero to multiply $ab$ by to get $0$...

You also have to show that $ab\neq 0$ in order for it to be a zero-divisor. Since $a$ is a unit, there is some $u$ such that $au=1$, and you know that $b\neq 0$. Suppose for the sake of a contradiction that $ab=0$... do you see how to finish?

Comment: I think so, thanks for the hint. Using x everywhere confused myself...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Unit scalings are invertible operations, so yield equivalent (in)equalities. $\ $ Therefore

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{array}{cc} \rm ub\ c = 0\\ \rm ub,c\ne 0\end{array} &\iff& \begin{array}{cc}\rm b\ c = 0\\ \rm b,c\ne 0\end{array} \\ \\
\rm 0\!\!-\!\!divisor\ ub &\iff&\rm 0\!\!-\!\!divisor\ b 
\end{array}$$

Comment: And by "Hint" you mean "Complete solution".